# How to use the function populate() correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I used the function `.populate()` to get the `equipements` grouped by `category`, so my model is like this

[image]

```
var mongoose = require('../config/db');
var EquipementSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    libelle: String,
    marque: String,
    category: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Equipement', EquipementSchema);
```

**Routes:**

```
router.get('/categorie_id', function(req, res, next){
    models.equipement.aggregate([
        {
            $group : {
                _id : '$categorie_id',
                equipements: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
            }
        }
    ].exec(function(err , results){

         if(err) res.json({error: err});
         res.json(results);
     }));   
});
```

[image]

The `results` is null when I used Postman

[image]

and when I used the `cmd` it works:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code here:

```
router.get('/categorie_id', function(req, res, next){
    models.equipement.aggregate([
        {
            $group : {
                _id : '$categorie_id',
                equipements: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
            }
        }
    ].exec(function(err , results){ // <-- typo here: missing a closing bracket after the pipeline array

         if(err) res.json({error: err});
         res.json(results);
     }));   
});
```

which should be

```
router.get('/categorie_id', function(req, res, next){
    models.equipement.aggregate([
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$categorie_id",
                "equipements": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
            }
        }
    ]).exec(function(err, results){ 
         if(err) res.json({error: err});
         res.json(results);
     });   
});
```

Use the **[`Model.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate)** function to populate document references, after correcting the aggregate pipeline query. Use the `results` array to populate the `_id` path as:

```
router.get('/categorie_id', function(req, res, next){
    models.equipement.aggregate([
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$categorie_id",
                "equipements": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
            }
        }
    ]).exec(function(err, results){ 
        if (err) res.json({error: err});
        models.equipement.populate(results, { "path": "_id" }, function(err, result) {
            if(err) res.json({error: err});
            console.log(result);
            res.json(result);
        });
     });   
});
```